# Trying to use Variable to redirect stderr to /dev/null in bash

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, exec, eval

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
[[ "${1}" == "debug" ]] && DEBUG='2>/dev/null' || DEBUG=''

{
    echo "a b c"
    echo "d e f" >&2
} ${DEBUG}
```

This doesn't work because of "sh: syntax error near unexpected token `${BLAH}'".  I am able to do something similar, like this:

```
eval echo "def" ${DEBUG}
```

but I can't do that with a large block of code.  An alternative might be to use "exec" to do the redirect in-line with the rest of my code, like:

```
[[ "${1}" == "debug" ]] && exec 2>/dev/null
```

but my shell hangs if I try to use exec in particular fashion.  Any ideas, cleaver friends?

Answer (score 0):

Create another fd:

```
[[ "${1}" == "debug" ]] && exec 7>/dev/null || exec 7>&2

{
    echo "a b c"
    echo "d e f" >&7
}
```

By the way are you sure that output should be nullified when `debug` argument is mentioned, or the other around instead?

A better way actually is to create a function:

```
if [[ "${1}" == "debug" ]]; then
    function debug {
        echo "$1" >&2
    }
else
    function debug {
        :
    }
fi

{
    echo "a b c"
    debug "d e f"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a script,

```
[[ $1 != debug ]] && exec 2>/dev/null
```

is actually what you're looking for. But you probably don't want to do it in an interactive shell.

Bash uses `stderr` for some pretty important things, not just alerting you about error conditions. For one thing, it uses `stderr` to print the command prompt, and (normally) to echo characters you type so that you can see them.

So when you `exec 2>/dev/null` in an interactive shell, bash continues to work, and it even continues to listen to you, but it can no longer respond. So it looks like its "hanging", but that's just an illusion. Try typing `Echo hello, me` (without being able to see what you type) and when you hit enter, you'll see the result of the echo, just like normal.

What is it that you're trying to do, by the way? Suppressing `/dev/stderr` is almost never the right thing...

Comment: It even happens with different _fd_ rather than `2>`, and with different shells such _Bourne Shel_l (`sh`)
If you choose any other number, the result is the same: "losing shell interaction".